# Json Serialisation Swift 3 type error

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I am using the following code to receive custom data from a push notification and I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1b0776cf0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b0777128).

on the following line:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (customDataString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as![String: Any]
```

How do I resolve this error?

```
func onPushAccepted(_ pushManager: PushNotificationManager!, withNotification pushNotification: [AnyHashable : Any]!, onStart: Bool) {
    print("Push notification accepted: \(pushNotification!)")

    let customDataString = pushManager.getCustomPushData(pushNotification)

    if customDataString != nil {
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (customDataString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]

        print("*** \(jsonData?["test"]!)")
    }
```

Comment: Clearly the JSON is an array, not a dictionary. And why are you force casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error:

> Could not cast value of **expected** type **Array** to **offered** type **Dictionary**

That means your JSON is an array, so

```
if let customDataString = pushManager.getCustomPushData(pushNotification) {   
   let data = customDataString.data(using: utf8)!
   let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [[String:Any]]
   ...
```

You can omit the `options` parameter, because `.mutableContainers` is useless in Swift anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much